# How to isolate $Q$ in $g=Q(p-c\ln{Q})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When I try to isolate $Q$ it happens that I don't know what to do because all I get is $Q$ in one side of the equation and $\ln{Q}$ in the other side.

I know it has something to do with the Lambert W function, but I don't know how to get to the final equation.

> I would like to know all the steps I have to do to isolate $Q$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x = -\frac{g}{cQ}$, then $$-cx = p+c\ln\left(-\frac{c}{g}x\right)$$ and hence $$e^{-cx} = e^p \left(-\frac{c}{g}x\right)^c.$$
This implies $$ e^{-x} = -\frac{c}{g}e^{\frac{p}{c}}x$$ and finally $$-\frac{g}{c}e^{-\frac{p}{c}} = xe^x.$$ Thus $x = W(-\frac{g}{c}e^{-\frac{p}{c}})$ and $$Q = -\frac{g}{c}W\left(-\frac{g}{c}e^{-\frac{p}{c}}\right)^{-1}.$$